# PostgreSQL/JDBC reading over 100k lines with IN clause

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

**Hi all!**
I read data from a file, which I then use to query in PG.
The file contains a large number of lines that are unique fields for the record (not keys).

I need to **read from a file** and **take from the database** an average of **500k records**

When reading cyclically with more than 5000 values in the IN request, the reading speed is very slow.

a simple example of the request I'm using:

```
SELECT * FROM schema.table WHERE table.param IN ('p1', 'p2','more'.....)
```

**Is there a more correct way to read such amounts of data in my conditions?**

Thank you for your answers

*P.S. I read that JDBC has a short size limit for IN clause, otherwise an exception will be thrown*

Comment: Load the file into a table and do all the work in the database.

Comment: Don't do it. Import the file into the database and go from there

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an index on that column?  I would recommend that you execute an EXPLAIN PLAN and look for a TABLE SCAN.  If you see one, please add an index to your query.

Do you have a UNIQUE constraint on that column?

I would consider a query with 5,000 values in an IN clause to be badly designed.

Answer (score 0):

Further to duffymo's answer:

Indexes are special lookup tables the database can use to speed up data fetches.

An index helps yoy to speed up SELECT statements and WHERE clauses ( this is your case) , but it slows down the data input process (i.e UPDATE and INSERT statements).

**NOTE:** Indexes can be created or dropped with no effect on the data.

##### HOW TO ADD INDEX

In this case, duplicate values are permitted:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_name (column1, column2, ...)
```

##### HOW TO ADD UNIQUE INDEX

Here, duplicate values are not permitted:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name
ON table_name (column1, column2, ...)
```